# Everytime I Resize My Car A Part Goes Missing Pygame How Do I Fix This?

Tags: python, html, css, python-3.x, pygame

recently I got helped with making a basic car physic but one problem I am having is that my car is to small and everytime I resize the car some part of the car goes missing [video](https://gyazo.com/d4156841e71d42d6ea162fb9a1cbe7fa) I am not sure how to fix this the car is way to small and I am trying to make a car parking game I need the car to be a little bigger[image]

my car class

```
pygame.display.set_caption("car game")
img = pygame.image.load("s23.png")
img = pygame.transform.scale(img,(img.get_width()+ 36,img.get_height()+ 36))

class Car:
    def __init__(self, x, y, height, width, color):
        self.x = x - width / 2
        self.y = y - height / 2
        self.height = height
        self.width = width
        self.color = color
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(x, y, height, width)
        self.surface = pygame.Surface((height, width)) # 1
        self.surface.blit(img, (0, 0))
        self.angle = 0
        self.speed = 0 # 2

    def draw(self): # 3
        self.rect.topleft = (int(self.x), int(self.y))
        rotated = pygame.transform.rotate(self.surface, self.angle)
        surface_rect = self.surface.get_rect(topleft = self.rect.topleft)
        new_rect = rotated.get_rect(center = surface_rect.center)
        window.blit(rotated, new_rect.topleft)

white = (255, 255, 255)
car1 = Car(300, 300, 73, 73, white) # 4
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
```

my main loop

```
runninggame = True
while runninggame:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            runninggame = False
    
    pressed = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    car1.speed *= 0.9 # 5
    if pressed[pygame.K_UP]: car1.speed += 0.5 # 6
    if pressed[pygame.K_DOWN]: car1.speed -= 0.5 # 6

    if pressed[pygame.K_LEFT]: car1.angle += car1.speed / 2 # 7
    if pressed[pygame.K_RIGHT]: car1.angle -= car1.speed / 2 # 7
    car1.x -= car1.speed * math.sin(math.radians(car1.angle)) # 8
    car1.y -= car1.speed * math.cos(math.radians(-car1.angle)) # 8
    
    window.fill((0, 0, 0)) # 9
    car1.draw()
    pygame.display.flip()
    clock.tick(60) # 10
pygame.quit()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You scale your image when you load it. Later when you instantiate a `Car` you pass in a `height` and `width` for the car and create a Surface with that dimension. However you do not scale the image to fit in that, you just blit the initial image onto that surface (which is the requested size). Blit'ing your image onto a smaller surface will cause it to be cropped to the size of the surface it is being blit'ed to.

To fix this, do not scale the image when you first load it. Just scale it when you create `self.surface` in the `__init__()` for `Car`.